# How to fix Ubuntu 10.10 black screen from terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10, x-server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 on an Intel Atom mainboard ([Intel D945GCLF2](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d945gclf2/sb/CS-029540.htm)) with CRT that has been running Ubuntu 9.x previously.
Both, Desktop live CD / installer and alternate install CD cause the screen to go black (and the status LED blinks).

I was able to get a bit further into the boot process with `nomodeset` as parameter with the Live CD, unfortunately I can't pass GRUB any parameters now that I have used the alternate Install CD by pressing 'e', it just boots.

So now I have Ubuntu installed, I get a terminal with CTRL-ALT-F1 but I don't know what I need to do now or how to adjust resolution or video settings from command line.

Comment: When I start the system with CRT off, it works. If CRT is detected, it does not because default resolution seems to be 1600x1200.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a screen when starting the system with CRT off.
I used an ethernet connection and remote desktop (from Windows with TightVNC and adjusted compression settings) to log in when screen black on subsequent restart. The resolution was set to 1600x1200 which is why the CRT could not cope. I manually changed resolution and subsequently set as default. On reboot, the CRT shortly loses it, but login window now is ok!